# Making a table responsive in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web, html-table, resize

```
<table align="center" border="0" border-collapse:="" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" collapse="" style="height: auto; width: 1229px; max-width: 100%;">
```

I'm wondering how can I make my table readjust itself, so when i'm resizing my browser window or on a mobile device the table adjust itself accordingly.

Comment: It depends on how you want it to readjust.
Tables have their own tags - <tr>,<td> etc, so there is limitation on creating whole new layouts depending on device / screen size it is being viewed in.
You could use <div> to structure the content, and use css ```display:table;```.
Alternatively you could use css grid or flexbox. Any of these could be options depending on exactly what you would like to do

Comment: I ran your table declaration through the W3C validator and it said align, cellpadding, cellspacing and border are obsolete - use CSS instead. I think these attributes are not true HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to use are media queries which allow you to select how and where your content is located on screen based on the size of the screen/device.

Take a look at these for further reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using CSS grid as a way of creating a responsive table if its possible for your use case

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I gave you an example of adaptive `table`. Adaptive fires at 800px width. Hope it will be helpful for you.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  thead {
    display: none;
  }
  tr {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
  td {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  td:before {
    content: attr(aria-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 3px 0 3px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E5E5E5;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">filed 1</th>
      <th scope="col">filed 2</th>
      <th scope="col">filed 3</th>
      <th scope="col">filed 4</th>
      <th scope="col">filed 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" aria-label="filed 1">simple text 1</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 2">simple text 2</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 3">simple text 3</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 4">simple text 4</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 5">simple text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" aria-label="filed 1">simple text 1</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 2">simple text 2</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 3">simple text 3</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 4">simple text 4</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 5">simple text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" aria-label="filed 1">simple text 1</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 2">simple text 2</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 3">simple text 3</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 4">simple text 4</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 5">simple text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" aria-label="filed 1">simple text 1</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 2">simple text 2</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 3">simple text 3</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 4">simple text 4</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 5">simple text 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" aria-label="filed 1">simple text 1</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 2">simple text 2</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 3">simple text 3</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 4">simple text 4</td>
      <td aria-label="filed 5">simple text 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that is best shown in a table then you will know how many columns you have and will have some idea of how wide relative to each other they ought to be. You will also have decided what you want to happen on a very narrow device - are the cells to be all squashed up to the whole row can be seen at once, or is the user to scroll horizontally through the cells if things don't fit well on the available screen? To cover this you probably want to set a min-width for either the table itself or its container.

Once that is worked out you can use CSS to style each cell relative to the overall width of the table. In the simplest case where you want them all the same width you could give them each x% of the width of the container you where x*number of columns = 100.

Otherwise you could use CSS selectors like td:nth-child(1) {width: 10%;} td:nth-child(2) {width:15%;} and so on as appropriate.

Similarly for cell height - which you may want to vary depending on the row number.

And so it goes on, but with CSS rather than the deprecated table-specific attributes, you have a lot of flexibility, for example on which rows and columns get what padding or color or borders as well as their basic dimensions.

You probably don't need to use media queries if you keep all the dimensions, apart from the max and min table width, relative.